# How to add/enqueue Custom CSS for a custom taxonomy page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, css, taxonomy, wp-enqueue-style

So this is what I have done for my homepage so I load css that only loads on my homepage

```
    function enqueue_frontend_assets(){
    if(is_page_template( 'homepage.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'homepage',  get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/homepage.css' );
    }
}
```

And it works just fine and only loads on the homepage.

I am trying to load the exact same file for my custom taxonomy page but it doesn't load.

```
    function enqueue_frontend_assets(){
    if(is_page_template( 'taxonomy-state.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'homepage',  get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/homepage.css' );
    }
}
```

What should I use instead to make sure it loads on all the custom taxonomy pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking against the template, you should use [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) which is one of the [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#a-taxonomy-page) in WordPress.

So in your function, you just need to use `is_tax( 'state' )` in place of `is_page_template( 'taxonomy-state.php')`, and your asset would only be loaded on the archive page for your custom `state` taxonomy.